# LXC container network speed issue

Tags: linux, networking, lxc, container

I am running openstack on LXC container and i found inside my LXC container network is very slow but from host its very fast

## HOST

```
[root@ostack-infra-01 ~]# time wget http://mirror.cc.columbia.edu/pub/linux/centos/7.5.1804/updates/x86_64/repodata/0d7e660988dcc434ec5dec72067655f9b0ef44e6164d3fb85bda2bd1b09534db-primary.sqlite.bz2
--2018-08-04 00:24:09--  http://mirror.cc.columbia.edu/pub/linux/centos/7.5.1804/updates/x86_64/repodata/0d7e660988dcc434ec5dec72067655f9b0ef44e6164d3fb85bda2bd1b09534db-primary.sqlite.bz2
Resolving mirror.cc.columbia.edu (mirror.cc.columbia.edu)... 128.59.59.71
Connecting to mirror.cc.columbia.edu (mirror.cc.columbia.edu)|128.59.59.71|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 4515677 (4.3M) [application/x-bzip2]
Saving to: ‘0d7e660988dcc434ec5dec72067655f9b0ef44e6164d3fb85bda2bd1b09534db-primary.sqlite.bz2’

100%[===========================================================================================================================================>] 4,515,677   23.1MB/s   in 0.2s

2018-08-04 00:24:09 (23.1 MB/s) - ‘0d7e660988dcc434ec5dec72067655f9b0ef44e6164d3fb85bda2bd1b09534db-primary.sqlite.bz2’ saved [4515677/4515677]


real    0m0.209s
user    0m0.008s
sys     0m0.014s
```

## LXC container on same host

```
[root@ostack-infra-01 ~]# lxc-attach -n ostack-infra-01_neutron_server_container-fbf14420
[root@ostack-infra-01-neutron-server-container-fbf14420 ~]# time wget http://mirror.cc.columbia.edu/pub/linux/centos/7.5.1804/updates/x86_64/repodata/0d7e660988dcc434ec5dec72067655f9b0ef44e6164d3fb85bda2bd1b09534db-primary.sqlite.bz2
--2018-08-04 00:24:32--  http://mirror.cc.columbia.edu/pub/linux/centos/7.5.1804/updates/x86_64/repodata/0d7e660988dcc434ec5dec72067655f9b0ef44e6164d3fb85bda2bd1b09534db-primary.sqlite.bz2
Resolving mirror.cc.columbia.edu (mirror.cc.columbia.edu)... 128.59.59.71
Connecting to mirror.cc.columbia.edu (mirror.cc.columbia.edu)|128.59.59.71|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 4515677 (4.3M) [application/x-bzip2]
Saving to: ‘0d7e660988dcc434ec5dec72067655f9b0ef44e6164d3fb85bda2bd1b09534db-primary.sqlite.bz2’

100%[===========================================================================================================================================>] 4,515,677   43.4KB/s   in 1m 58s

2018-08-04 00:26:31 (37.3 KB/s) - ‘0d7e660988dcc434ec5dec72067655f9b0ef44e6164d3fb85bda2bd1b09534db-primary.sqlite.bz2’ saved [4515677/4515677]


real    1m59.121s
user    0m0.002s
sys     0m0.361s
```

I don't have any fancy configuration of any limit set for network, i have other host which is working fine and max speed, what do you think wrong here

```
kernel version Linux ostack-infra-01 3.10.0-862.3.3.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP
```

CentOS 7.5

Comment: Have you checked the block io prioritization? Try running "lxc-group -n ostack-infra-01_neutron_server_container-fbf14420 blkio.weight".  I believe anything under 1000 will de-prioritize the IO of the container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

Host machine had following setting, it was causing my dmesg flood with lots of kernel error stack.  (7 - debug level).

```
[root@lxc ~]# cat /proc/sys/kernel/printk
7   4   1   3
```

I have changed it to:

```
[root@lxc ~]# cat /proc/sys/kernel/printk
3   4   1   3
```

Later I found I had `iptables --checksum-fill` rules in `iptables` which was generating lots of checksum error which causing kernel stack error food into `dmesg`.